# Shuffling 2 different decks end up the with same card order

Tags: c#

So I'm writing a small war card game program for practice and one thing I'm having some trouble understanding is why my function is returning the same deck for both human and cpu.

```
public static void TheirDecks(Player hum , Player cpu)
    {
        hum.myDeck.GenerateDeck();
        cpu.myDeck.GenerateDeck();

        hum.myDeck.Shuffle();
        cpu.myDeck.Shuffle();
    }
```

so the TheirDecks() method is found in my Create class.

```
public void GenerateDeck() // Must use this to populate deck
    {
        CurrentlyInDeck = new List<Card>(52);
        int place = 0; // tracks which card number
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            for (int f = 0; f < 13; f++)
            {
                Card card = new Card();
                CurrentlyInDeck.Add(card);
                CurrentlyInDeck[place].suit = (Suit)i;
                CurrentlyInDeck[place].face = (Face)f;
                place++;
            }
        }
    }

    public void Shuffle() 
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        Card holder = new Card();
        int random;

        for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++)
        {
            random = rand.Next(0, 51);
            holder = CurrentlyInDeck[i];
            CurrentlyInDeck[i] = CurrentlyInDeck[random];
            CurrentlyInDeck[random] = holder;
        }
    }
```

Those 2 are found in another class called Deck. When I run the following:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Create.TheirDecks(human , cpu);
        human.myDeck.PrintDeck();
        Console.WriteLine();
        cpu.myDeck.PrintDeck();
    }
```

The print deck function prints out the same exact deck. Why is that? Thank you for your time.

Comment: move `Random rand = new Random();` outside from the `Shuffle` fucntion more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767999/random-number-generator-only-generating-one-random-number)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep a single instance of `Random` & keep using `Next` for the same instance. 
Try the following solution:

```
private static readonly Random rand = new Random(); 

public void Shuffle() 
{
    Card holder = new Card();
    int random;

    for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++)
    {
        random = rand.Next(0, 51);
        holder = CurrentlyInDeck[i];
        CurrentlyInDeck[i] = CurrentlyInDeck[random];
        CurrentlyInDeck[random] = holder;
    }
}
```